# show different data from database using select option

Tags: php, javascript, html, database, sorting

I tried to show different data in table when the user choose different option from the first page...and I tried to give sort function using javascript..however, the shown data is same even though the user chose different option...

this is my code for my main page

test.html

```
 <form action="index2.php" method="post">
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">test</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Foreign Agent Country</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
        <select name="country">
        <option value="US">United States</option>
        <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
        <option value="JP">Japan</option>
        </select> 
        </td>
      </tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value-"Submit">
        </td>
    </table>
    </form>
```

and this is my code to retrieved the data from database which is connected to my javascript

index2.php

```
 <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/select-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!--id class -->
<div id="contentHolder">

    <?php
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

    //connect to database
    //select the database
    mysql_select_db("fak_databases");
    //submit button
    if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
    {
        $country = $_POST['country'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['orderby'])){
        $order = $_GET['orderby']; 
        $sort = $_GET['sort'];

        if($country == 'US') {  
        // query to get all US records
            if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1' && $order != 'wipo_applicant1_state')$order = "wipo_applicant1_city";
                if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                    $sql = "SELECT `wipo_applicant1_city`, `applicant1_addr1`, `wipo_applicant1_state`, `invention-title` FROM `auip_wipo_sample` WHERE applicant1_country='US' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                    //here we reverse the sort variable
                    if($sort == "asc"){
                        $sort = "desc";
                    }
                else{
                    $sort = "asc";
                }

        }
        else if($country == 'NZ') {  
        // query to get all US records  
        //$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='US'");   
            if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1' && $order != 'wipo_applicant1_state')$order = "wipo_applicant1_city";
                if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                    $sql = "SELECT `wipo_applicant1_city`, `applicant1_addr1`, `wipo_applicant1_state`, `invention-title` FROM `auip_wipo_sample` WHERE applicant1_country='NZ' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                    //here we reverse the sort variable
                    if($sort == "asc"){
                        $sort = "desc";
                    }
                else{
                    $sort = "asc";
                }

        }
        else if($country == 'JP') {  
        // query to get all US records  
        //$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auip_wipo_sample WHERE applicant1_country='US'");   
            if($order != 'wipo_applicant1_city' && $order != 'applicant1_addr1' && $order != 'wipo_applicant1_state')$order = "wipo_applicant1_city";
                if($sort != 'asc' && $sort != 'desc')$sort = "asc";
                    $sql = "SELECT `wipo_applicant1_city`, `applicant1_addr1`, `wipo_applicant1_state`, `invention-title` FROM `auip_wipo_sample` WHERE applicant1_country='JP' ORDER BY ".mysql_real_escape_string($order)." ".$sort; 

                    //here we reverse the sort variable
                    if($sort == "asc"){
                        $sort = "desc";
                    }
                else{
                    $sort = "asc";
                }

        }
    }else {
        $order = "";
        $sort = "asc"; 
        $sql = "SELECT `wipo_applicant1_city`, `applicant1_addr1`, `wipo_applicant1_state`, `invention-title` FROM `auip_wipo_sample`";
    }
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $row_counter = 0; 

    $icon = "";
    echo "<table  border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\">\n";
    echo "<tr>\n"; 

    // first column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "wipo_applicant1_city"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }

    //print the result
    echo "<a href='index2.php?orderby=wipo_applicant1_city&sort=".$sort."'>City</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";


    // second column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "applicant1_addr1"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='index2.php?orderby=applicant1_addr1&sort=".$sort."'>Address</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";


    // third column
    echo "<th>";
    $icon = "";
    if($order == "wipo_applicant1_state"){
        if($sort == "asc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/up.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
        if($sort == "desc"){
            $icon = "<img src=\"images/down.png\" class=\"arrowSpace\"/>";
        }
    }
    echo "<a href='index2.php?orderby=wipo_applicant1_state&sort=".$sort."'>State</a>".$icon;
    echo "</th>\n";
    echo "</tr>";

    //fetch the result
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        //give a different color for row
        if($row_counter % 2){
            $row_color="bgcolor='#FFFFFF'";
        }else{
            $row_color="bgcolor='#F3F6F8'";
        }
        echo "<tr class=\"TrColor\" ".$row_color.">";
        echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_city'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['applicant1_addr1'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "<td>" . $row['wipo_applicant1_state'] . "</td>\n";
        echo "</tr>";
        $row_counter++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
</div>

</body>
```

show-all.js

```
function SelectAll(btn) {
    var blnVal = false;
    if (btn.value == "Select All") {
        btn.value = "Unselect All";
        blnVal = true;
    }else {
        btn.value = "Select All";
        blnVal = false;
    }
    var d = document.forms["auip_wipo_sample"];
    if(d["auip_wipo_sample[]"] == null)
    {}
    else if (d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].length == null) {
        d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].checked = blnVal;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < d["auip_wipo_sample[]"].length; i++) {
            d["auip_wipo_sample[]"][i].checked = blnVal;
        }
    }
}
```

there is no error when the code is execute but the result is always same

anyone know what is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hitting your else statement, because all your country-specific code is only being checked if orderby is set, so if it's not set, it will do your else, which will be the same code every time.

Also, there is too much code to cleanup, but I'll make a list for you of what you can do to clean that code up by maybe 75%

1. Check if ordered by is set in its OWN if statement
2. Check if sort is set in its OWN if statement
3. find out which country was selected in the form
4. make a query using all those options for example:

   $sql = "SELECT column1, column2, etc FROM auip_wipo_sample  $countryWhereStatement   $sort  $orederedby ";

If you do the logic correctly, the $country variables will contain the keyword WHERE country = 'US', the $sort variable will contain ASC or DESC and the order by will contain the keyword ORDER BY columnname

This can be done to save space and make things easier to read, and even more dynamic.

Also, try not to use backticks unless absolutely necessary.  They are necessary on really old versions of MySQL(I mean REALLY old) and if the field or table name is the same as a MySQL keyword.  Otherwise, you shouldnt need them.